# How to grab children from xml file as a string

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking for an occurance of a certain tag in my xml file. If i find an occurance then i want to get its immediate children tags (not their child tags)

Is this possible? If so what do i need to look in to ?

Thanks

```
<Footballer>
    <Player>
        <Number />
        <Team>
            <Division />
            <Position />
        </Team>
        <Country />
        <Birthdate />
    </Player>
</Footballer>
```

if player was the input for example then the tags Number, Team, Country Birthdate would be returned

Comment: Show some exmaple data of a simplified example input and expected output. Also, show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use linq to xml:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
List<string> urlList = doc.Descendants("yourparent");
                      .Select(x => insert value you want to select).ToList();
```